# nginx reverse proxy+rundeck is not wokring as expected

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rundeck

I want to use rundeck with NBINX reverse proxy but not working as exptected.

rundeck is at:
http://host.domain:4440/rundeck
nginx reverse proxy is at:
https://host.domain/rundeck

nginx's configuration:

```
   location /rundeck/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.102:4440/rundeck/;
}
```

rundeck's customize:
RUNDECK_SERVER_CONTEXTPATH=/rundeck
RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED=true

https://host.domain/rundeck shows:
[image]

Is there any way to fix this problem ?
The browser's development console shows the following error:
Cannot read: https://host.domain/rundeck/assets/menu/knockout.mapping.min.js.map HTTP error 404、net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

A solution:
Use http reverse proxy instead of https reverse proxy:

```
apache2 as a http reveverse proxy:
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /rundeck/ http://host.domain:4440/rundeck/
    ProxyPassReverse /rundeck/ http://host.domain:4440/rundeck/

nginx as a reverse proxy:
    location /rundeck/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://host.domain:4440/rundeck/;
    }

framework.properties:
framework.rundeck.url = http://host.domain/rundeck/

rundeck-config.properties:
grails.serverURL=http://host.domain/rundeck/
server.servlet.context-path = /rundeck
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `grails.serverURL` (at rundeck-config.properties file, `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` Docker env var) parameter is pointing to the proxy exit URL (`https://host.domain/rundeck` in your case).

Also, try with the latest version of Firefox/Chrome ([same issue](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5874)).

Comment: grails.serverURL is:
grails.serverURL=https://host.domain/rundeck
framework.rundeck.url is:
framework.rundeck.url = https://host.domain/rundeck

Comment: I may found a solution:
If reverse proxy is http, not https, the reverse proxy worked fine.
http
reverse proxy
http
rundeck
may be required.

Comment: Awesome, please add your solution as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

A solution: Use http reverse proxy instead of https reverse proxy:

```
apache2 as a http reveverse proxy:
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /rundeck/ http://rundeckhost.domain:4440/rundeck/
    ProxyPassReverse /rundeck/ http://rundeckhost.domain:4440/rundeck/

nginx as a reverse proxy:
    location /rundeck/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://rundeckhost.domain:4440/rundeck/;
    }

framework.properties:
framework.rundeck.url = http://reverseproxy.domain/rundeck/

rundeck-config.properties:
grails.serverURL=http://reverseproxy.domain/rundeck/
server.servlet.context-path = /rundeck
```

Answer (score 0):

lets assume your rundeck is running in internal server with domain name "internal-rundeck.com:4440" and you want to expose it on "external-rundeck.com/rundeck" domain through nginx---follow below steps

step 1:
**In rundeck**

```
RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL="external-rundeck.com/rundeck"
RUNDECK_SERVER_CONTEXTPATH=/="/rundeck"
RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED=true
```

set above configurations in deployment file as environment variables

step 2:
**In nginx**

```
location /rundeck/ {

proxy_pass http://internal-rundeck.com:4440/rundeck/;

}
```

add this in your nginx config file it works